# Display term with custom post title

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I created a custom post type `jobs`.

The list with the title of each custom post type are well displayed.

Marketing director
Webdesigner
Lead developer

But I didn't manage to display tags of custom taxonomy `contracts` in each custom post (in bold below).

Marketing director 
**Freelance** - published on June 20

Webdesigner 
**Contract** - published on June 26

Here's my query :

```
$context['jobs'] = Timber::get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'jobs',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
         'taxonomy' => 'contracts'
     )
));
```

And my loop :

```
{% for job in jobs %}
<a href="{{ job.link }}" class="jobs__link">
    <p class="jobs__label">{{ job.jobs_title }}</p>
    <p class="jobs__info"><span class="tag-color">???</span> — published on {{ job.date }}</p>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's because the main query doesn't return the taxonomy terms, you need a separate query for that. You can use `wp_get_post_terms` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/

Comment: @disinfor, this is for the current page ? I tried and that return an empty array

Comment: You need to pass the post id and taxonomy to get the terms `wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'contracts' );` I'm not sure with twig how to get the id for the `job` object - maybe `job.id`. This would be inside your loop.

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: @disinfor, I tried, but nothing is display, I'm trying to display a list with title of job and the term associated for each job

Comment: According to the documentation, you can do `<p>{{ jobs.terms('contracts')|join(', ') }}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
{% for job in jobs %}
<a href="{{ job.link }}" class="jobs__link">
    <p class="jobs__label">{{ job.jobs_title }}</p>
    <p class="jobs__info"><span class="tag-color">{{ jobs.terms('contracts')|join(', ') }}</span> — published on {{ job.date }}</p>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

According to the documentation using the twig template, you can get the terms of the taxonomy by using `{{ jobs.terms('contracts')|join(', ') }}`

https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#terms